# GWT DataGrid with SimplePager, Last Page Issue

Tags: gwt, datagrid, simplepager

I'm using GWT DataGrid with SimplePager to show a my Data,

The Component shows the first pages correctly, but the last page  shows always 10 rows (10 = SimplePager.pagesize) even if we have less then 10 rows to display.

AnyOne have an idea about yhis issue ?

Thanx.

Comment: can you please show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue before. The small difference is that I was using Celltable instead of DataGrid.

The problem is coming from a known bug of gwt which you can see the detail on [its github page](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/6162). Obviously it has been fixed yet.

The workaround is to subclass the SimplePager and create your custom pager class.

```
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.SimplePager;
import com.google.gwt.view.client.Range;

public class CustomPager extends SimplePager {

public CustomPager() {
    this.setRangeLimited(true);
}

@Override
public void setPageStart(int index) {
    if (this.getDisplay() != null) {
        Range range = this.getDisplay().getVisibleRange();
        int pageSize = range.getLength();
        index = Math.max(0, index);
        if (index != range.getStart()) {
            this.getDisplay().setVisibleRange(index, pageSize);
        }
    }
}

}
```